# Problem when creating a new project in android studio 3.6.3

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.6.1

Problem when creating a new project
in android studio 3.6.3
10:10 PM    Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: app. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.

Comment: I have been seeing this too, but I have not come up with a reproducible scenario. I have just been ignoring the warning box, and everything seems to be working OK. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`